# Union two Arrays by colnames

Tags: arrays, r

I have two named arrays of different length:

```
x = setNames(c(0.3,0.5,0.1,0.2),c(4,5,7,9))
y = setNames(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

and I want to union (or better: add) them by their column names, resulting in:

```
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
0.0  0.0  0.3  0.5  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.2   0.0
```

Perhaps I should mention that one of the arrays is actually of class `table`, which is as far as I understand it, nothing different from a named array.

Comment: Try `y[names(y) %in% names(x)] <- x; y`  In the example, all the names in `x` are also in `y`.  Is it possible that some names in `x` are not in `y` are you want that also in the output.

Comment: @akrun It suffices `y[names(x)]<-x`. Your solution can be wrong if the order is not preserved.

Comment: @nicola Yes, you are right.  I didn't check it.

Comment: Is your goal to pad a `table` result with zero values? Then you should make the input to `table` a `factor` and specify the factor `levels` to include the values with zero occurence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subset your element indicating the names rather than the indices. This works with your example:

```
  y[names(x)]<-x
  #  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
  #0.0 0.0 0.3 0.5 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.2 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a solution but rather a workaround. Also, this way you sum (`add` if a understood correctly your question) by names.

***Data***

```
x = setNames(c(0.3,0.5,0.1,0.2),c(4,5,7,9))
y = setNames(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

***Code***

```
library(dplyr)

df <- full_join(data.frame(var=x) %>% mutate(names = names(x)), 
      data.frame(var=y) %>% mutate(names = names(y))) %>% group_by(names) %>% 
      summarise(var=sum(var)) %>% arrange(as.numeric(names))

z <- setNames(df$var, df$names)
z
```

***Result***

```
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
1.0  1.0  1.3  1.5  1.0  1.1  1.0  1.2  1.0
```